# regex Vowels to 1337 Numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

How to change all vowels to numbers with regex and javascript?

Using the `L33T` rule:

`a` to `4`, `e` to `3`, `i` to `1`, `o` to `0` and `u` can be `u`

Here an example: `jorge` becomes `j0rg3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var text = 'Manuel Marques de Sousa, Conde de Porto Alegre (Rio Grande, 13         de junho de 1804 – Rio de Janeiro, 18 de julho de 1875), apelidado de "O Centauro de Luvas", foi um militar, político, abolicionista e monarquista brasileiro.';
console.log(text);
console.log(text.replace(/([aeiou])/gi, function (todaRegex, vogal) {
obj = {
    a: '4',
    e: '3',
    i: '1',
    o: '0',
    u: 'u'
};
return obj[vogal.toLowerCase()];
}));
```